# Saving and Loading Treeview using XML

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe, lazarus

**Note**

Sorry in advance for the long post, I though it would be best to put as much information on as possible rather than fill the gaps when needed.

Note although I have tagged this as Delphi as well and do own and still use Delphi XE I am now using Lazarus as my primary IDE, I simply cannot afford to purchase the newer Delphi versions and now Lazarus is becoming more stable it makes sense to me to make the switch to Lazarus.

For this question I have included a zip attachment with project source, although written in Lazarus it will really help with the question I have, hence the comments in the first paragraph.

---

**Overview**

Onto the question, I have a Object that owns several classes as TLists.

I represent this data in a Treeview and there is no way of knowing how many levels and nodes will be present in the tree as they are dynamically created at runtime. One limitation I have set is that the Top level nodes will be fixed, meaning they cannot be deleted or renamed - these are what I will call RootGroups.

The Treeview will be populated with items and groups, every node added to the Treeview will have its own Object assigned to the data to identify each item correctly. I am going to show an example screenshot now to give a better idea before carrying on:

[image]

As you can see I have the two top most nodes, *Object1Root* and *Object2Root*. If you notice the buttons on the right, they allow adding group and items to the Treeview but they become disabled if they don't belong in that part of the Treeview. For example you cannot add *Object2Group* or *Object2Item* under *Object1Root*.

Basically everything in the Treeview has its own Pointer to a Object. Each Object I am deriving from a Base Object. This Base Object has properties to store the position of where it is found in the Treeview, like this:

```
type
  TBaseObject = class
  private
    FName: string;
    FGroup: string;
    FNodeLevel: Integer;
    FNodeIndex: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create(AName: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Name: string read FName write FName;
    property Group: string read FGroup write FGroup;
    property NodeLevel: Integer read FNodeLevel write FNodeLevel;
    property NodeIndex: Integer read FNodeIndex write FNodeIndex;
  end;
```

I can then derive my other classes from the Base Object, like this:

```
type
  TObject1RootGroup = class(TBaseObject)
  public
    constructor Create(AName: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure ToSave(const XMLDoc: IXMLDocument; var Root, Node: IXMLNode);
  end;

  TObject1Group = class(TBaseObject)
  public
    constructor Create(AName: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure ToSave(const XMLDoc: IXMLDocument; var Root, Node: IXMLNode);
  end;

  TObject1Item = class(TBaseObject)
  private
    FSomeVal1: string;
    FSomeVal2: string;
  public
    constructor Create(AName: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure ToSave(const XMLDoc: IXMLDocument; var Root, Node: IXMLNode);
  published
    property SomeVal1: string read FSomeVal1 write FSomeVal1;
    property SomeVal2: string read FSomeVal2 write FSomeVal2;
  end;
```

The *Main Object* that holds all these classes looks like this:

```
type
  TMyObject = class(TObject)
  private
    FName: string;
    FObject1Groups: TList;
    FObject1Items: TList;
    FObject2Groups: TList;
    FObject2Items: TList;
  protected
    procedure FreeObjects;
  public
    constructor Create(AName: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure Save(FileName: string);
    function Load(Filename: string): Boolean;
  published
    property Name: string read FName write FName;

    property Object1Groups: TList read FObject1Groups;
    property Object1Items: TList read FObject1Items;
    property Object2Groups: TList read FObject2Groups;
    property Object2Items: TList read FObject2Items;
  end;
```

When I save the *Main Object* to XML I first iterate the whole TreeView and then assign to each Object the Node data such as Parent, Level, Index etc. The output XML File based on the first image would look like this:

[image]

Note: The SomeVal parts are not important as I never bothered writing anything to the Objects.

Really what I should do is Save to the XML just as the Treeview is represented. I am not too familar with XML as I am still getting to grips with it, but I think the output should look something like this: (written in Notepad)

```
<XML Name="test.xml">
  <Counts Object1Groups="3" Object1Items="5" Object2Groups="2" Object2Items="1" />

  <TObject1RootGroup Name="Object1Root" Group="" NodeLevel="0" NodeIndex="0"
     <TObject1Item Name="Item1" Group="Object1Root" NodeLevel="1" NodeIndex="0" SomeVal1="" SomeVal2="" />
     <TObject1Item Name="Item2" Group="Object1Root" NodeLevel="1" NodeIndex="1" SomeVal1="" SomeVal2="" />
     <TObject1Group Name="Group1" Group="Object1Root" NodeLevel="1" NodeIndex="2" />
     <TObject1Item Name="Item3" Group="Object1Root" NodeLevel="1" NodeIndex="3" SomeVal1="" SomeVal2="" />
     <TObject1Group Name="Group2" Group="Object1Root" NodeLevel="1" NodeIndex="4" />
        <TObject1Item Name="Item1" Group="Group2" NodeLevel="2" NodeIndex="0" SomeVal1="" SomeVal2="" />
        <TObject1Group Name="Group1" Group="Group2" NodeLevel="2" NodeIndex="1" />
           <TObject1Item Name="Item1" Group="Group1" NodeLevel="3" NodeIndex="0" SomeVal1="" SomeVal2="" />  

<TObject2RootGroup Name="Object2Root" Group="" NodeLevel="0" NodeIndex="1" 
     <TObject2Group Name="Group1" Group="Object2Root" NodeLevel="1" NodeIndex="0" />
     <TObject2Group Name="Group2" Group="Object2Root" NodeLevel="1" NodeIndex="1" />
        <TObject2Item Name="Item1" Group="Group2" NodeLevel="2" NodeIndex="0" SomeVal1="" SomeVal2="" />
</XML>
```

Then I could load the TreeView from the XML. The problem is I only really know how to save the XML as I currently am, I know some kind of recursion etc is needed and this is where I would struggle, and particularly rebuilding the Tree from the XML File.

**Attachment**

It has taken me a few hours to strip down my actual project code into an example that is easier to read and understand, it is written in Lazarus and uses the **OmniXML library**, I have only included the source units no project file.

Download it here (the password is stackoverflow): http://www34.zippyshare.com/v/16401041/file.html

Ultimately my question is:

- How to save to XML with correct hierarchy structure.
- How to load the XML and rebuild the Treeview to exactly how it was before save.

Many thanks.

Comment: You've asked this twice now. Perhaps remove the other Q.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry it was a genuine mistake I forgot to delete it. I needed a drink after spending ages writing the question and putting together the examples.

Comment: OK, I understand. This is a much better Q, +1.

Comment: Are you saving in xml so you can use the file for other reasons? Just that you could use TTreeView's Read and Write component methods to do this.  If that's too much of a departure, the code is worth looking at.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I thought the way I am doing it is better because it is essentially serializing my objects in a more cleaner way. I used to use WriteComponentRes and I found it very dirty, now I am using Lazarus saving to XML makes sense for its readability and portability, especially if I ever cross-compile. For what its worth in my real code I do store more then basic types, streamed data etc which I base encode.

Comment: Makes sense, as would sheer curiousity :)

Comment: Have to give me a bit of time for a full answer, its a good stick of code. What Xml component are you using?

Comment: Something I don't understand.  Why do what you're doing (NodeLevel/NodeIndex) when you can represent a TreeView in pure XML anyway and reproduce it without these things?

Comment: @Glenn1234 I guess this is why I asked the question as I really am not sure how to save it all correctly, I guess I did it that way thinking I could write and read the XML using the Level/Index as references or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a raw draft for further development.

```
unit TreeXML;

interface

uses Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, xmldom, XMLIntf, msxmldom, XMLDoc, ActiveX, ComObj, ComCtrls;

Type

  TTreeToXML = Class
  private
    FDOC: TXMLDocument;
    FRootNode: IXMLNode;
    FTree: TTreeView;
    procedure IterateRoot;
    procedure WriteNode(N: TTreeNode; ParentXN: IXMLNode);
  Public
    Constructor Create(Tree: TTreeView);
    Procedure SaveToFile(const fn: String);
    Destructor Destroy; override;
  End;

  TXMLToTree = Class
  private
    FTree: TTreeView;
    procedure IterateNodes(xn: IXMLNode; ParentNode: TTreeNode);
  Public
    Procedure XMLToTree(Tree: TTreeView; Const FileName: String);
  End;

implementation

{ TTreeToXML }

constructor TTreeToXML.Create(Tree: TTreeView);
begin
  FTree := Tree;
  FDOC := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  FDOC.Options := FDOC.Options + [doNodeAutoIndent];
  FDOC.Active := true;
  FDOC.Encoding := 'UTF-8';
  FRootNode := FDOC.CreateElement('Treeview', '');
  FDOC.DocumentElement := FRootNode;
  IterateRoot;
end;

Procedure TTreeToXML.WriteNode(N: TTreeNode; ParentXN: IXMLNode);
var
  CurrNode: IXMLNode;
  Child: TTreeNode;
begin
  CurrNode := ParentXN.AddChild(N.Text);
  CurrNode.Attributes['NodeLevel'] := N.Level;
  CurrNode.Attributes['Index'] := N.Index;
  Child := N.getFirstChild;
  while Assigned(Child) do
  begin
    WriteNode(Child, CurrNode);
    Child := Child.getNextSibling;
  end;
end;

Procedure TTreeToXML.IterateRoot;
var
  N: TTreeNode;
begin
  N := FTree.Items[0];
  while Assigned(N) do
  begin
    WriteNode(N, FRootNode);
    N := N.getNextSibling;
  end;
end;

procedure TTreeToXML.SaveToFile(const fn: String);
begin
  FDOC.SaveToFile(fn);
end;

destructor TTreeToXML.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FDOC) then
    FDOC.Free;

  inherited;
end;

{ TXMLToFree }

Procedure TXMLToTree.XMLToTree(Tree: TTreeView; const FileName: String);
var
  Doc: TXMLDocument;
begin
  FTree := Tree;
  Doc := TXMLDocument.Create(Application);
  try
    Doc.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    Doc.Active := true;
    IterateNodes(Doc.DocumentElement, NIL);
  finally
    Doc.Free;
  end;
end;

Procedure TXMLToTree.IterateNodes(xn: IXMLNode; ParentNode: TTreeNode);
var
  ChildTreeNode: TTreeNode;
  i: Integer;
begin
  For i := 0 to xn.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
  begin
    ChildTreeNode := FTree.Items.AddChild(ParentNode,
      xn.ChildNodes[i].NodeName);
    IterateNodes(xn.ChildNodes[i], ChildTreeNode);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Example call

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  With TTreeToXML.Create(TreeView1) do
    try
      SaveToFile('C:\temp\test.xml');
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  With TXMLToTree.Create do
    try
      XMLToTree(TreeView2, 'C:\temp\test.xml')
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

The XML used would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Treeview>
  <Object1Root NodeLevel="0" Index="0">
    <Item1 NodeLevel="1" Index="0"/>
    <Item2 NodeLevel="1" Index="1"/>
    <Group1 NodeLevel="1" Index="2"/>
    <Group2 NodeLevel="1" Index="3">
      <Item1 NodeLevel="2" Index="0"/>
      <Group1 NodeLevel="2" Index="1">
        <Item1 NodeLevel="3" Index="0"/>
      </Group1>
    </Group2>
  </Object1Root>
  <Object2Root NodeLevel="0" Index="1">
    <Group1 NodeLevel="1" Index="0"/>
    <Group2 NodeLevel="1" Index="1">
      <Item1 NodeLevel="2" Index="0"/>
    </Group2>
  </Object2Root>
</Treeview>
```

Comment: I have had some time to work with this now, and apart from making some changes to work with OmniXML this seems to be working as I had hoped. I still need to change a lot of things to store my objects in the nodes and read them back but for now I accept your answer and if I run into problems I will post a new question. Many thanks for your brilliant answer.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the for the inconvenience due to my lack of experience with OmniXML.

Comment: definitely no inconvenience at all, in fact making these small changes myself helped me understand a bit better, I am new to all this XML stuff.

Comment: Great answer exactly what I also needed.  Tiny spelling mistake - you have { TXMLToFree } rather than { TXMLToTree }.  An additional suggestion to improve the answer (something I will be doing for myself) is to make it so that the XMLtoTree section will compare nodes and/or merge Trees.  This is helpful in case the XML is updated by another app, then you can just merge in the new branches rather than having duplicate branches.  Another suggestion is to of course include other properties, such as ImageIndex, StatusIndex, etc.  Good answer, upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt of my own.  Uses the MSXML 6.0 type library.  Not too fancy, but seems to do the job.

```
unit ttreexml;
// treeview to XML, XML to treeview by Glenn1234,
// may be used with proper credit given
interface
  uses msxml2_tlb, comctrls, dialogs, sysutils;

type
// saves TTreeView as XML file.
TTreeViewToXML = class
  private
    doc: IXMLDOMDocument;
    FTree: TTreeView;

    procedure XMLPopulate(BaseNode: TTreeNode; DataItem: IXMLDOMelement);
  Public
    Constructor Create(Tree: TTreeView);
    procedure SaveToFile(filename: string);
  end;

// loads TTreeView from XML file
TXMLToTreeView = class
  private
    doc: IXMLDOMDocument;
    FTree: TTreeView;

    procedure XMLLoad(BaseItem: TTreeNode; DataItem: IXMLDOMNode);
  Public
    Procedure XMLToTree(Tree: TTreeView; Const FileName: String);
  end;


implementation
constructor TTreeViewToXML.Create(Tree: TTreeView);
begin
  FTree := Tree;
end;

procedure TTreeViewToXML.XMLPopulate(BaseNode: TTreeNode; DataItem: IXMLDOMelement);
var
  SubItem: IXMLDOMElement;
  selnode: TTreeNode;
begin
  SelNode := BaseNode;
  while selnode <> nil do
    begin
      if SelNode.HasChildren then
        begin
          SubItem := doc.CreateElement('Group');
          SubItem.setAttribute('Value', SelNode.Text);
          DataItem.AppendChild(SubItem);
          XMLPopulate(SelNode.GetFirstChild, SubItem);
        end
      else
        begin
          SubItem := doc.CreateElement('Item');
          SubItem.setAttribute('Value', SelNode.Text);
          DataItem.AppendChild(SubItem);
        end;
      SelNode := SelNode.GetNextChild(SelNode);
    end;
end;

procedure TTreeViewToXML.SaveToFile(filename: string);
 var
   topnode: IXMLDOMElement;
   selnode: TTreeNode;
 begin
   //create DOM document instance
   doc := CoDOMDocument.Create;
   doc.async := false;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   topnode := doc.createElement('TreeView');
   doc.appendChild(topnode);
   selnode := FTree.Items.GetFirstNode;
   XMLPopulate(SelNode, topnode);
   doc.save(FileName);
 end;

 procedure TXMLToTreeView.XMLLoad(BaseItem: TTreeNode; DataItem: IXMLDOMNode);
   var
     item1, item2: IXMLDOMNode;
     attr: IXMLDOMNamedNodeMap;
     CurrItem: TTreeNode;
   begin
     Item1 := DataItem;
     CurrItem := nil;   // compiler complains if I don't do this
     while Item1 <> nil do
       begin
         attr := item1.attributes;
         item2 := attr.nextNode;
         while item2 <> nil do
           begin
             CurrItem := FTree.Items.AddChild(BaseItem, Item2.NodeValue);
             item2 := attr.nextNode;
           end;
         if item1.nodename = 'Group' then
           XMLLoad(CurrItem, Item1.Get_firstChild);
         Item1 := Item1.Get_nextSibling;
       end;
   end;

   Procedure TXMLToTreeView.XMLToTree(Tree: TTreeView; Const FileName: String);
    var
      item1: IXMLDOMNode;
    begin
     //create DOM document instance
      doc := CoDOMDocument.Create;
      doc.async := false;
      FTree := Tree;
     //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      if doc.load(FileName) then
        begin
          FTree.Items.BeginUpdate;
          FTree.Items.Clear;
          Item1 := doc.documentElement.Get_firstChild;
          XMLLoad(nil, Item1);
          FTree.Items.EndUpdate;
        end
      else
        begin
          MessageDlg(Format ('Error loading XML document.'#13 +
                             'Error number: %d'#13 +
                             'Reason: %s'#13 +
                             'Line: %d'#13 +
                             'Column: %d', [doc.parseError.errorCode,
                             doc.parseError.reason,
                             doc.parseError.line,
                             doc.parseError.linePos]), mtError, [mbOK], 0);
        end;
    end;
 end.
```

Quick sample XML output:

```
- <Group Value="Delphi 3">
- <Group Value="BIN">
  <Item Value="BOWF520.DLL" /> 
  <Item Value="BOWFVC.DLL" /> 
  <Item Value="BRC32.EXE" /> 
  <Item Value="BRCC32.EXE" /> 
  . . .
  <Item Value="DELPHI32.EXE" /> 
  <Item Value="DELPHIMM.DLL" /> 
  . . .
  </Group>
  <Item Value="DeIsL1.isu" /> 
- <Group Value="Demos">
- <Group Value="ACTIVEX">
- <Group Value="DELCTRLS">
  <Item Value="ABOUT1.DFM" />
```