# How do I convert code between OmniXML and Delphi's own XML library?

Tags: xml, delphi, lazarus

I recently started using OmniXML primarily because it can be used for both Delphi and Lazarus.

I myself am a beginner when it comes to XML, and this is where I hope I can learn some things or avoid doing any bad things I may already be doing.

For this I am going to use another question I have as a reference: [Saving and Loading Treeview using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578683/saving-and-loading-treeview-using-xml)

In one of the answers by [bummi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1699210/bummi), I think he is using standard XML in Delphi where I am using OmniXML in Lazarus, so the code he posted in his answer would not compile. I have it working now after changing some of the code but I need to know if the following is correct:

---

**(1) Variable Types**

*Delphi*

```
TTreeToXML = Class
private
  FDOC: TXMLDocument;
  FRootNode: IXMLNode;
```

*OmniXML*

```
TTreeToXML = Class
private
  FDOC: IXMLDocument;
  FRootNode: IXMLElement;
```

---

**(2) Creating the XML Document**

*Delphi*

```
FDOC := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
```

*OmniXML*

```
FDOC := CreateXMLDoc;
```

---

**(3) Freeing the XML Document**

*Delphi*

```
if Assigned(FDOC) then
    FDOC.Free;
```

*OmniXML*

I cannot see a way to Free the document?

---

**(4) Attributes**

*Delphi*

```
Procedure TTreeToXML.WriteNode(N: TTreeNode; ParentXN: IXMLNode);
var
  CurrNode: IXMLNode;
  Child: TTreeNode;
begin
  CurrNode := ParentXN.AddChild(N.Text);
  CurrNode.Attributes['NodeLevel'] := N.Level;
  CurrNode.Attributes['Index'] := N.Index;
  Child := N.getFirstChild;
  while Assigned(Child) do
  begin
    WriteNode(Child, CurrNode);
    Child := Child.getNextSibling;
  end;
end;
```

*OmniXML*

```
Procedure TTreeToXML.WriteNode(N: TTreeNode; ParentXN: IXMLNode);
var
  CurrNode: IXMLNode;
  Child: TTreeNode;
begin
  CurrNode := ParentXN.AddChild(N.Text);
  CurrNode.Attributes.SetValue('NodeLevel', IntToStr(N.Level));
  CurrNode.Attributes.SetValue('NodeIndex', IntToStr(N.Index));
  Child := N.getFirstChild;
  while Assigned(Child) do
  begin
    WriteNode(Child, CurrNode);
    Child := Child.getNextSibling;
  end;
end;
```

---

**(5) Options**

*Delphi*

```
FDOC.Options := FDOC.Options + [doNodeAutoIndent];
```

*OmniXML*

The Document is saved with indents automatically, I cannot find any options?

---

**(6) Active**

*Delphi*

```
FDOC.Active := true;
```

*OmniXML*

I see no way of setting such a property to True or False?

---

**(7) Encoding**

*Delphi*

```
FDOC.Encoding := 'UTF-8';
```

*OmniXML*

Again I see no such option?

---

So basically I guess I would like to know what are the differences between the Delphi XML and OmniXML implementations.

Are the changes I made the correct way of doing it or not?

The properties I cannot find such as Options and Encoding, how would I implement this in OmniXML?

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't call "MSXML" standard, nor is it Delphi's Own. It's Window's/Microsoft's own API. Wrappers for the Windows MS XML DLLs are included in the box, but it would be clearly to just say "convert to MSXML API".

Comment: @WarrenP I see your point, but I think I referred to it as Delphi's own simply because the units come with Delphi as standard, and in Lazarus they don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**(1) Variable Types**

```
TTreeToXML = Class
private
  FDOC: IXMLDocument;
  FRootNode: IXMLNode;
```

**(2) Creating the XML Document**

OK.

**(3) Freeing the XML Document**

No need to free. Its interface based. You can explicitly free it like this:

```
FDOC := nil;
```

provided you don't have any other references to it.

**(4) Attributes**

Probably OK. Did not look into it to much.

**(5) Options**

You control indentation when you save XML document.

```
procedure TXMLDocument.Save(const FileName: string; const OutputFormat: TOutputFormat = ofNone);
```

This is what the OutputFormat is for. Also check the "PreserveWhiteSpace" property when loading the XML from file or stream.

**(6) Active**

What is Active? I see no need for it.

**(7) Encoding**

Use:

```
function CreateProcessingInstruction(const Target, Data: XmlString): IXMLProcessingInstruction;
```

To write it like this for instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

This is if you save the document and you want to specify the encoding. For reading OmniXML can read almost any encoding provided that the BOM is there.

---

Anyway OmniXML is very similar to TXMLDocument. Changes are mostly in the programmers interface and OmniXML is compatible with MSXML.

You can also check my [SimpleStorage](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/simplestorage/) which is a set of interfaces on top of OmniXML that simplify it a LOT. Just check the demos and see what I mean. But it does not work under Lazarus unfortunately.

Comment: @Ӎσᶎ although it might seem like 7 questions in one, I felt it was better then making 7 single questions which would effectively move every other question down the list.

Comment: I agree with Blobby, the questions are on the same topic and grouped.